# Load related data without foreign key constraint in ef-core-2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

I want to load related entities data `Parent` by using Eager Loading O/RM pattern. But I can't specify a foregin key constraint on `ParentId` because it creates a cycle which is not allowed. Currently, I'm using an inner join to load Parent data explicitly.

Here is my Domain Model that I'm using.

```
[Table("Category")]
public class CategoryDM
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Parent")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public CategoryDM Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to load related entities like this? or any other recommended way to achieve this.

```
var result = _context.Category.Include(e => e.Parent);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it creates a cycle that is not allowed`. This is called hierarchical data which is a very common use case and works perfectly with the parent id column. In fact, I have this exact model in the project I'm working on right now.

Comment: @AvinKavish ParentId is creating relationshiop with itself.

Comment: Yeah that's fine. The relationship can be created and used to eager-load as long as you make sure there are no self-referencing loops in the data. But that's up to you to check.

Comment: @AvinKavish When I specify FK it gave me this error on `update-database`. 
   "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Category_Category_ParentId' on table 'Category' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine, here is an exemplary working model.

Model

```
    public class Category : ISelfRelated<Category>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public Category Parent { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Category> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Model configuration

```
            category.HasOne(c => c.Parent)
                .WithMany(c => c.Children)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .IsRequired(false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @AvinKavish. That's really solved my problem.