# Entity Framework Core code-first foreign key with optional linked entity

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a table of files which I want to reference in 2 other tables.
Each file is exclusive to one of these tables, which means that I have foreign keys which has no entity in at least one of the linked tables, some files might have a filled key which is linked to no entity at all (since it will be crated at a later time).

Relation: (1 -> n)

```
Item <- File -> Image
```

This causes a foreign key exception on insert/`SaveChanges`, since the database was unable to find the linked entity.

I searched for a solution but was unable to find any articles which address this issue and the solutions I came up with had all at least one code smell.

Question: how do I link these 3 tables without getting a DB exception and producing code/db smells?

Or is maybe the entire data architecture faulty and I should try something different (and if what)?

Solutions which I came up with but would like not to use:

- no foreign key but a new query
- use an intermediary table which has only entities of linked entities (file -> link -> item)
- splitting the `Files` table into `ItemFiles` and `ImageFiles` (I heard this was a DB smell)

Other Information:

- .NET Core 3.1
- EF Core: latest
- Database: Sqlite

Shortened models:

```
public class FileData
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public ImageData Image { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string HashKey { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class Item
{
    public FileData[] Files { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string HashKey { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class ImageData
{
    public FileData[] Files { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string HashKey { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Database configuration:

```
public class FileDataConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<FileData>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FileData> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(file => file.Id);
        builder.HasIndex(file => file.HashKey);
        // ...
    }
}

public class ItemConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Item> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(item => item.Id);
        builder.HasMany(item => item.Files)
            .WithOne(file => file.Item)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasForeignKey(file => file.HashKey)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasPrincipalKey(item => item.HashKey);
        builder.HasIndex(file => file.HashKey);
        // ...
    }
}

public class ImageDataConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ImageData>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ImageData> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(image => image.Id);
        builder.HasMany(image => image.Files)
            .WithOne(file => file.Image)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasForeignKey(file => file.HashKey)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasPrincipalKey(image => image.HashKey);
        builder.HasIndex(image => image.HashKey);
        // ...
    }
}
```

**This Code Throws The Exception**

```cs
// both examples throw an exception, independent of each other
//example 1:
dbContext.Files.Add(
    new File(){
        HashKey="1"
    }
);
dbContext.SaveChanges();

//example 2:
dbContext.Files.Add(
    new File(){
        HashKey="2"
    }
);
dbContext.Items.Add(
    new Item(){
        HashKey="2"
    }
);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You should also show the code that causes the exception.

Comment: The Exception is thrown on SaveChanges, after I added an entity without link

Comment: I assume `FIle` is `FileData`? Anyway, you don't enter entities "without link". `Hashkey` is a foreign key.

Comment: But I need a list with all files and their HasheKeys (for algorithm reasons), and I want to link items to this list via the Hashkey. Since not all files are items/images, I am looking for a solution to represent this link using EF Core.
If this is a foreign key or not is secondary, I am just looking for the correct solution to represent this relation.
that means, not storing "unlinked" files is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to ditch the foreign keys since I don't need updates on the other entities and start the file-query by hand.
Adding the Files as Property didn't seem to be possible, since the error kept to be thrown [(I tried this solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372689/load-related-data-without-foreign-key-constraint-in-ef-core-2-1).

List of used constraints:
Item.Id => Key
Item.Hash => Indexed, Unique

Image.Id => Key
Image.Hash => Indexed, Unique

File.Id => Key
File.Hash => Indexed, not Unique

One of the reasons I decided to keep the IDs of Item and Image was that other entities refer to these mostly via ID, not hash and the hash could change, requiring a lot of updates.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your `FileData` entity should contain `Guid` foreign keys to both `Item` and `ImageData` entities, not just navigation properties i.e. `Guid ItemId` and `Guid ImageId`. For example:

```
public class FileData
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; set;}
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public Guid ImageId {get; set; }
    public ImageData Image { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string HashKey { get; set; }
    // ...
 }
```

Also in Fluent Api when configuring both `Item` and `ImageData` this configuration should be enough

```
 builder.HasMany(item => item.Files)
        .WithOne(file => file.Item)
        .IsRequired(false)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Comment: The Problem is that I would have to check for all linked items / files on database edit, which I would like to automate by using the hash.
My Solution in the end was to ditch the foreign key, make the HashKey unique and indexed (in Item & ImageData) and make a select statement when I need the file paths for an item. This eliminates error cases of faulty/missing updates and keeps everything automatically up to date without loosing too much performance